# What is the "standard reference" for cascade forward neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

What is the "standard reference" that firstly describes or surveys in details the cascade forward neural network? This kind of net is available in matlab toolbox for long [cascadeforwardnet](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/cascadeforwardnet.html) (as early as 1990's), but I can't find the original reference. Please note that it seems NOT the cascade-correlation network.

Answer (score 1):

Please take my answer with a pinch of salt as I am only vaguely familiar with this particular kind of NN architecture:

*Scott E. Fahlman and Christian Lebiere.

The Cascade Correlation Learning Architecture. 
Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems pages 524–532, 1990.*

Answer (score 1):

As Ngiann notes, Fahlman and Lebiere (1989) is the original paper. The pdf is widely available on the Internet, including [this address](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2937&context=compsci).

I wasn't sure from reading your question if you just wanted the original paper that launched CasCor, or the best "go-to" reference, or a list of alternatives. Since Fahlman and Lebiere naturally didn't cover a lot of the variants or experiments with CasCor that came after 1989, I'll list a few good ones I've encountered, all of which are available on the Internet without a paywall. So far, my impression is that there isn't one single dominant paper or book that acts as a sort of CasCor Bible, but there are some that are clearly worth reading.

• The most comprehensive treatment I've seen to date is Balázs, Gabor, "Cascade-Correlation Neural Networks: A Survey," which can be found [here](http://papersdb.cs.ualberta.ca/~papersdb/uploaded_files/1033/additional_ccnnsurvey2009.pdf). There may be better ones, but I haven't run across them yet.

• Another general reference is Prechelt, Lutz, 1996, "Investigation of the CasCor Family of Learning Algorithms," which is [available online](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/neurnetw97.pdf).

• For some empirical testing of cascade correlation, try Yang, Jihoon and Honavar, Vasant, "Experiments with the Cascade-Correlation Algorithm" at [this address](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/Papers/ijcnn91.pdf).

• One noteworthy variant is Fahlman's extension of cascade correlation to RNNs, in Fahlman, Scott E., 1991, "The Recurrent Cascade-Correlation Architecture," which can be found [here](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3052&context=compsci).

• Another well-written article involves the extension of cascade correlation to RBFs. See Lu, Weiying and Harrington, Peter de B., 2009, "Radial Basis Function Cascade Correlation Networks," pp. 1045-1068 in Algorithms, Vol. 2. I found it at [this Google address](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI0qKK4OHNAhXHMSYKHds9CsgQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F1999-4893%2F2%2F3%2F1045%2Fpdf&usg=AFQjCNEjYRttFXW1D6F-Um7EfqEPiP80Bg).

I hope that helps. I've also run into a few decent case studies, but I don't think they'd answer your question. The three articles on variants and experimentation are not general treatments per se, but they do contain good summaries of CasCor nets.